# Hiding sheet before sending email via WebApp (google app script)

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

My goal is to send the data from the sheet to an email. I want the sheet hidden before and after sending to the email, so if anyone looks at the sheet, all data is hidden. I was able to get my code to work when I was not trying to hide the sheet. The following code does not do anything if the data is hidden.

```
function Onopen() { 
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var menu = ui.createMenu('Custom Menu');
var item = menu.addItem('Sales Agent','salesAgent');
  item.addToUi();
}

function email(){
 

  // Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
 

  // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
  // Or use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<<SPREADSHEET URL>>");
   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sales Report").activate();
 
  var lrow = sheet.getLastRow()
 
  var rangeEdit = sheet.getRange("D2").getA1Notation();
   
 
  var client = sheet.getRange("E4").getValue();
  var salesperson = sheet.getRange("E3").getValue();
  var email = sheet.getRange("E5").getValue();
  var spemail = sheet.getRange("E2").getValue();
 
  var address = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
 var status = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
 
 



  // Subject of email message
  var subject = "Sales report;

  // Email Body can  be HTML too with your logo image - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
  var body = "Hi " + client + ", "+ "<br><br> Please find the attached ". <br><br>  Let us know if you have any questions.<br><br>  Thank you,<br><br> " + spmail;
     
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
Logger.log(aliases); //returns the list of aliases you own
Logger.log(aliases[0]); //returns the alias located at position 0 of the aliases array
 
  // Base URL
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
  */

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=letter'                       // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=True'                    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'           // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();


  //make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs  
  var blobs;


    // Convert your specific sheet to blob
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

    //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
    blobs = response.getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + '.pdf');


  // Define the scope
  Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());
   
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
 
      name:'Sales Department',
      bcc: spemail,
      noReply: true,
      attachments:[blobs]    
    });  
  getSheetByName("Sales").hidesheet();
}    

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('html filename without extension');
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? By the way, in your script, it seems that at `var subject = "Sales report;` and `var body = ,,,`, the text is not enclosed by the double quotes. But you say `The following code does not do anything if the data is hidden.`. So I'm worry that you might have miscopied of your current script. Can you confirm your current script again? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to help me. The script works if the Sales report sheet is not hidden. Therefore, I’m trying to unhide the sheet run script and hide sheet again automatically or though GAS. Thanks Again!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.